# Facebook Application Design Question

Tags: zend-framework, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Iam coding a dating application for facebook. The application has to have a standalone web application part and a Iframe based part which runs inside facebook canvas.

I want to know good ways to design the application. Iam using zend framework, so here is my idea.

One approach that am planning to use is this -

The application folder to contain 2 controllers, index controller being the entry point of the standalone web application and another controller- FacebookController to be the entry point of the Iframe being run inside facebook canvas. Both of them calling the same view files which get written based on which controller is writing to them.

The second approach is to have one single controller as the entry point and use 2 layout files. One for the standalone web application and one for the facebook canvas app.

The reason for choosing these approaches in that the authentication mechanism of the two applications is different.

To get an idea, have a look at www.areyouinterested.com,  Iam planning to do something similar to what they have done.

Please suggest me what would be the best way to go around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first choice is best.

Two Controllers. Two layouts. Common views.

This gives you flexibility to change around a lot of one or the other without breaking the opposite one.

If you feel ambitions, I would even go with two modules.  If your application is structured well enough each module will have common components that are re-usable.